# Экспорт в csv из pandas, ошибка формирования таблицы

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Формирование списка в csv:

```
model_spisok=[]
cena_spisok=[]
for result in spisok:
        model = result.find('a').text
        cena = result.find('span').text
        price_dict = {'model':model_spisok,'cena':cena_spisok}
        model_spisok.append(model)
        cena_spisok.append(cena)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=price_dict, columns=['model','cena'])
df.sort_values('model', ascending=True)
```

Результат:

[image: Список]

Формируем csv:

```
df.to_csv('Mob_price.csv', sep=',')
```

Результат:

[image: Неправильная таблица]

Как сделать так что бы все писалось в отдельных колонках?

Comment: похоже Excel у вас не принимает запятую в качестве разделителя. `df.sort_values('model', ascending=True)` - вернет отсортированный DF, но исходный DF не изменится, поэтому сделайте: `df = df.sort_values('model', ascending=True)`

Comment: Благодарю за помощь